# particle effect display badly ripple on the android

Tags: android, effects, particles

I am creating particle effect to simulate the street lamp. It looks good and smoothly on the ios and pc but there is some ring like the ripples on the android platform. Is there any thing I can do to fix it? Please check the screen shot for the detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Unity. Please check image compression and displaying parameters for your build, looks like this is an issue with number of colors in result render(16 bit on android and 24/32 bit on iOS/PC).

Comment: thanks for your advise,I will check if there is a problem with number of colors. For the compression, I have tried with uncompress textures and with same result as the screen shot. BTW, I'm not using Unity. Our engine base on irrlicht.

Comment: @snail what format you are using for storing compressed images in resources?

Comment: I have tried with ETC and RGBA8888(uncompress) format. Same result.

Comment: @snail what about EGL config?

Comment: The EGL config was used the 16 bit as the pixes size. I will try with 32 bit.

Comment: Sorry that I forget to confirm the solution. Yes, the issue was fixed by use 32bit pixes size.